# What' wrong with this syntax?

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I am sure this is simple, but I don't get why...
Why is this wrong?

```
echo "<img src='".bloginfo('template_directory')."/systemdata/next.png' border=0 id='NavImage'>";
```

If I do it like this, it works:

```
echo "<img src='";
echo bloginfo('template_directory');
echo "/systemdata/next.png' border=0 id='NavImage'>";
```

What do I do not get? I want to write nice code and the second example is not very elegant I think.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the bloginfo return?

Comment: as a side note, if you want to write elegant code, you shouldn't directly echo strings, but you should use some view template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong function, [`bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) already outputs / echoes so you cannot use it when you want to concatenate strings (nor should you `echo` it...).

Instead you could use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) as that returns a string:

```
echo "<img src='".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/systemdata/next.png' border=0 id='NavImage'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as far as code  elegant factor is concerned:

```html
$blogingo=bloginfo('template_directory');
echo "<img src=$blogInfo/systemdata/next.png' border=0 id='NavImage'>";
```